# How to add custom emoji in discord.ui button components

Tags: discord.py

I'm utilizing buttons for my bot via discord_ui and discord.py, but I wanna know if it's possible to do custom emojis. I tried doing it like so:

```
[Button(custom_id = "next", label = "Next", color = "gray", emoji = "<:emoji_name:id:>")] # emoji itself is redacted for the sake of the question but that's the format
```

But, it returns as an invalid emoji, even if it follows the `str` or `discord.Emoji` format it requires as far as I know. How should I go about this? If, again, it's even possible.

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should post an answer and rollback the edit you've just made. Questions are for questions :)

Comment: Thanks for the notice! Still quite new in using this so ^^'

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been months later but I had found a solution.

To use a custom emoji in your button you need to fetch it first and assign it to a variable, then use that on your button.

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
   emoji = await ctx.guild.fetch_emoji(id)

   await ctx.send("test", components = [Button(custom_id = "test", label = "Test", color = "gray", emoji = emoji)])
```

Your emoji should pop up then. If there's a more elegant solution let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, but for future user.

For custom emoji you need to use `discord.PartialEmoji(name, id, animated)` instead of `<:emoji_name:id:>` when using ui.Button.

Comment: ui.Button does not support `discord.PartialEmoji`. It only takes `discord.Emoji` or `str`. I had found a solution to it though so I'll edit it in my post

Comment: ui.Button support discord.PartialEmoji since I just used it. 
`discord.ui.Button(emoji=discord.PartialEmoji.from_str("<:name:id>") ...`